# JSON.parse(...) not working as expected, dot syntax not working

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to use `JSON.parse(...)` against a JSON string, but for some reason when I try to dot (.) access the object, I get an "undefined" on the nodes that I know exist in the JSON.  Shouldn't `JSON.parse(string)` return an Object?

Here's my code

```
var notificationText = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
console.log('notificationText Object Stringified: ' + JSON.stringify(notificationText));
console.log('NotificationText Object Not Stringified: ' + notificationText);
console.log('NotificationText.Notification Object: ' + notificationText.notification);
```

Here's the Console output for the first "`console.log(...)`":

```
notificationText Object Stringified: "{\"notification\":{\"body\":\"this is coolfgsdfsfdsfdsdfsdfsfds\",\"title\":\"Whoa\",\"data\":{\"url\":\"http://www.yahoo.com\"},\"requireInteraction\":true}}"
```

Here's the Console output for the second "`console.log(...)`":

```
NotificationText Object Not Stringified: {"notification":{"body":"this is coolfgsdfsfdsfdsdfsdfsfds","title":"Whoa","data":{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com"},"requireInteraction":true}}
```

Here's the Console output for the third "`console.log(...)`":

```
NotificationText.Notification Object: undefined
```

Here's my JSON in a easier to read format:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "body": "this is coolfgsdfsfdsfdsdfsdfsfds",
        "title": "Whoa",
        "data": {
            "url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
        },
        "requireInteraction": true
    }
}
```

My question is, why am I getting "undefined" when I try to dot syntax the "notificationText" object?

Comment: `notificationText` is still a string. You’re concatenating it with a string and seeing JSON instead of `[object Object]`. Is `event.data` being double-encoded a bug?

Comment: You're concatenating an object to a string, and then logging it. Try console.log('notificationText.notification', notificationText.notification); and see what happens.

Comment: I thought JSON.parse(...) should return an object?  Provide it a JSON string and the return value is an Object type?  Or no?

Comment: Not sure where the undefined is coming from, works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0ro1ugqf/)

Comment: As Ry said - your data looks double stringified before arrive in your code.
try `var notificationText = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(event.data.text()));`
if it works - then go up to the code where is your event comes from and find why it was stringified twice.

Comment: @Ry- you sir, are magical.  That was the issue.  You and Yuri got it.. I had to do a double JSON.parse

Comment: @Ry- if you make that an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the Object with string. You should go for exact value like

```
console.log('NotificationText.Notification Object: ' + notificationText.body);
```

Or if you still want to print the full object the way you were doing then put comma (,) instead of **+** like:

```
console.log('NotificationText.Notification Object: ', notificationText.notification);
```